# How to override the style of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice?

Tags: android

I use adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cur, cols, views) to create a multiple choice control,
but I'm not satisfied of the style of the textview in the multiple choice control, so I have to use the following code to create a new layout of a multiple choice control.
It works well, but I don't think it's a good way, is there any good code? Thanks!

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                 R.layout.mysimple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                 cur, cols, views);

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

**mysimple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml**

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"

/>
```

Comment: gothrough the 'custome adapters' in android

Answer (score 3):

## Simple.

Use `<include>`.

Create a new XML layout.

```
     <include android:id=”@+android:id/simple_list_item_multiple_choice”
     android:layout_width=”match_parent”
     android:layout_height=”match_parent”
     layout=”@layout/title”/>
```

You can override all the layout parameters (any `android:layout_*` attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend [BaseAdapter](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html&ei=CtyuUZGKKIiNrgf5u4DoCg&usg=AFQjCNHnKayBKyrhl9kc9mtkSEsip6wqXg&sig2=VlLMuCgNYp5CPP9pe1MrSw) to create a custom Adapter.With A custom adapter each row of listview uses a xml layout and hence you can create a custom layout for rows .

Example code of custom adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] StrValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] StrValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.StrValues = StrValues;
    }

    // getView that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // create a new LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view;
        view = null;
        convertView = null;// avoids recycling of list view
        if (convertView == null) {

            view = new View(context);
            // inflating grid view item
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_label);
            textView.setText(StrValues[position]);

        }

        return view;
    }

    // Total number of items contained within the adapter
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return StrValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Setting adapter:

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // setting adapter on listview
    listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, StrValues));
```

Links of examples:

[example 1](http://blograchita.wordpress.com/tag/custom-list-adapter/)
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter?rq=1)

R.layout.list_view_item is the custom xml for your list view ,in which you can add desired views .

Comment: if you have to do some thing that's not provided by default ,then there's no other choice .AFAIK it can be done only by custom adapter

Comment: This is such a complex way to achieve such a simple task IMHO.