# Change text color of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android, android-listview, multichoiceitems

I am trying to figure out how I can change the text color of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`

I know you can create your own listview with checkboxes but I really do not want to have to do that as the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` works perfectly, I would just like to know how to change the Text color.

I have come accross [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932895/how-to-override-the-style-of-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-multiple-choice) but I do not understand how I can use the most voted up answer.

How can I override `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` textview so I can change the color of it. Thank you.

Comment: yes you can create a custom layout but in your question "but I really do not want to have to do that as the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice works perfectly, I would just like to know how to change the Text color." ... so i just thought that you want to only change the color...
but for custom layout narendra is right ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make custom layout - `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml` like this -

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
/>
```

and use it in place of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml`

Answer (score 3):

You can change color easily.
You just have to override the getView() method.
And inflate the **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice** in particular view. now you can access the whole template. 
So that you can get the TextView used in this template by finding using id **android.R.id.text1**. after that you can change the behavior of textview.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, your_data_container) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(InvitationFlowActivity.this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setTextColor("Your_color");
            }
        };
```

And if  you are using custome adapter then you can also override the same getView() method and you can customize it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.
1. Override the getView method
2. Use custom layout instead of standard layout.

No. 2 is better as you have more control on the same and you can edit at your ease.
`Alt+Click` will clone the required layout to your `res/layout` folder.
Make changes to the new layout and use it in the adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.text_change,listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Here listItems is the String array of list.
text_change.xml is the updated layout xml
listView is your listview in the main layout.

In order to dynamically update color of content use the following code

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(CoffeeShop.this,DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    TextView txtV = (TextView)view;
                    txtV.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextView txtV = (TextView)view;
                    txtV.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence)"These Methods are yet to be made public", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
        };
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_opt);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

Adding onclicklistner for the view will allow updating the color of the text upon clicking. You can add respective logic as to which color should the text be displayed.