# TextChangedListener will not executed in listview

Tags: android, listview, search

Hi I have an ListFragment class. What I want is to be able to filter the list according the text in the search field. But it happens nothing when I type something in search field. I fetch the data from server and put it dynamically in listview:

**ListFragment:**

```
public class TopVotedUsersFragment extends ListFragment implements
        FetchDataListenerTopUser, OnRefreshListListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        top_user_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_topuser, container,
                false);

        search =(EditText) top_user_view.findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

        //Fetch data 
        initViewAll();

        l.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Search listener
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // Do nothing

                adapter.getFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Do nothing
            }

        });

        return top_user_view;
    }

    private void initViewAll() {

        String url = "http://xxxxxxxx/xxx.php";

        FetchDataTaskTopUser task = new FetchDataTaskTopUser(this);

        task.execute(url);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<ApplicationTopUser> data) {

        p.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // create new adapter
        adapter = new ApplicationAdapterTopUser(getActivity(), data);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          

    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public interface OnRefreshListener {
        public void onRefresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class ApplicationAdapterTopUser extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationTopUser>
        implements Filterable {
    private List<ApplicationTopUser> items;
    List<String> arrayList;      
    List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    ImageLoader imgLoader;
    String text;

    public ApplicationAdapterTopUser(Context context,
            List<ApplicationTopUser> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listrow_topuser, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.listrow_topuser, null);
        }

        ApplicationTopUser app = items.get(position);

        if (app != null) {

            TextView rank = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            ImageView pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileImage);

            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.uname);
            TextView points = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.points2);
            ImageView flag = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            TextView user_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userid);

            if (rank != null) {

                int begin = 1;
                int pos = position + begin;
                rank.setText("" + pos);

            }

            if (pic != null) {

                String sIcon = app.getPic();

                imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getContext());
                // int loader = R.drawable.loader;

                imgLoader.DisplayImage(sIcon, pic);

            }

            if (username != null) {
                username.setText(app.getUsername());
            }

            if (points != null) {
                points.setText("" + app.getPoints());
            }

            if (flag != null) {
                String sIcon = app.getFlag();

                imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getContext());
                // int loader = R.drawable.loader;

                imgLoader.DisplayImage(sIcon, flag);

            }

        }

        return v;
    }

     @Override
     public Filter getFilter() {
         Filter filter = new Filter() {

             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
             @Override
             protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                 arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                 notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
             }

             @Override
             protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                 FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                 List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                     mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                 }

                 /********
                  * 
                  *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                  *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                  *
                  ********/
                 if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                     // set the Original result to return  
                     results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                     results.values = mOriginalValues;
                 } else {
                     constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                     for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                         String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                         if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                             FilteredArrList.add(data);
                         }
                     }
                     // set the Filtered result to return
                     results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                     results.values = FilteredArrList;
                 }
                 return results;
             }
         };
         return filter;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You should override the getfilter() method

Comment: where is your adapter?

Comment: oh ok I just saw a empty filter method in my adapter class. What should I put in the method?

Comment: I did say getFilter() method :-)

Comment: ok I did. I followed this solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android), but still no success

Comment: What have you done till now? Please edit your question and put your code that you have used so far.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result

Comment: ok I updated both ListFragment class and Adapter Class...In ListFragment now I call getFilter(); in listener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61211/discussion-between-nabin-and-sini).

Comment: anyone who can help?

Comment: No unfortunately not...