# Filter listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Im trying to filter my listview items by the get_tema method = something.
The problem is I cant manage to make it work, if i do like `if (poiAtual.getTema().equals("EXAMPLETEMA"))` fill the holder.nome and etc it wont do what i want because it will anyway put a blank item on listview.

Below is my adapter!

Anybody can give a suggestion?
Thanks

```
private class POIListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<POI> {
    public POIListAdapter() {
        super (Lista.this, R.layout.item_listview, POIs);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
            holder.nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePOI);
            holder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
            holder.foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }
     else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }


        POI poiAtual = POIs.get(position);

        //TextView id=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(poiAtual.get_id()));
        //TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePOI);
        holder.nome.setText(poiAtual.get_nomePOI());
        //TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTema);
       // phone.setText(poiAtual.get_tema());
        //TextView descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        holder.descricao.setText(poiAtual.get_descricao());
      // ImageView ivFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
       //ivContactImage.setImageURI(poiAtual.get_imagemURI());


        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("lista_"+poiAtual.get_imagemURI(),"drawable",getPackageName());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(resId);
        //holder.foto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android

Comment: Means you just want to display data which it contains particular string?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Exactly thats it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you called getView it is too late.
You should filter your array and then call the adapter passing the filtered data,
otherwise you will get empty lines because getView is called for each array element.

You can consider to filter the listview using filterable interface and a custom filter.

Comment: Can you do a example of that? Thanks

Comment: You should create a Filter class that extends Filter and override two methods. In more detail, performFiltering is the method where the filter is applied and there you should implement your filtering logic. The adapter has to implement Filterable interface. If you want to know more i've a post about it: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html