# How do I make my ArrayAdapter (For AutocompleteTextview) return all results with substring provided

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to get my AutocompleteTextview to return all results containing the sub-string provided, however it only returns the results that START with the sub-string provided.

The current result set is

```
0:  "CMPN0004:Gigrig"
1:  "CMPN0002:NYDA"
2:  "CMPN0003:TEST"
```

and it correctly performs the autocomplete if I type "CMP", however it does not provide any results if I type "TEST" or "Gigrig"

```
final AutoCompleteTextView campaignTxt = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.CampaignTxt);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TripAddActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, campaigns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getFilter`, as [described here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301216/5349594)

> You are having problem, mainly because you are using custom object. If
>   you pass a String or int value to array adapter its know how to filter
>   it. But if you pass custom object default filter implementation have
>   to no idea how to deal with that.
>
> Although it is not clear what you are trying to do in your filter i
>   recommend you following steps.
>
> 1. Proper implementation of `ListTO`, although it has nothing to do with your goal right now
> 2. Implement custom filter
> 3. return your filter
>
> **Implement custom filter**
>
> First thing you have to do is, `implements` `Filterable` from your
>   array adapter.
>
> Second, provide implementation of your `Filter`
>
> ```
> Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
>         @Override
>         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
>            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
>            ArrayList<ListTO> tempList=new ArrayList<ListTO>();
>            //constraint is the result from text you want to filter against. 
>            //objects is your data set you will filter from
>            if(constraint != null && objects!=null) {
>                int length=objects.size();
>                int i=0;
>                 while(i<length){
>                   ListTO item=objects.get(i);
>                       //do whatever you wanna do here
>                   //adding result set output array     
>
>                       tempList.add(item);
>
>                       i++;
>                 }
>                 //following two lines is very important
>                 //as publish result can only take FilterResults objects
>                 filterResults.values = tempList;
>                 filterResults.count = tempList.size();
>           }
>           return filterResults;
>       }
>
>       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>       @Override
>       protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
>         objects = (ArrayList<ListTO>) results.values;
>           if (results.count > 0) {
>              notifyDataSetChanged();
>           } else {
>               notifyDataSetInvalidated();
>           }  
>       }
>    };
> ```
>
> Last step,
>
> ```
> @Override
>    public Filter getFilter() {
>       return myFilter;
>   }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I'm implementing that code now. Would you mind explaining why the adapter works when I use the first characters  of the records but does not work when I use the middle characters?

Comment: It's simple - default Filter implementation works that way. You can see for yourself. Lines 483 and 491: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter