# Android TextWatcher search with sql like %%?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView`. I want to search in `Listview` by `arrayAdapter`. Android `textwatcher` helped me in this topic. But it searches only one to one coupling. For example: I type "ger" to search Germany. It lists just "Germany", but my list also contains Algeria and Nigeria. So, how can I search with like %% command as SQL in adapter?

```
public ArrayAdapter<?> adapter;
     @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(title);

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View dialogLayout = null;

                if (adapter != null) {
                    dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_list_filter, null);

                    filterText = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.search_box);
                    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialogListView);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);
                    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                }

                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.text_cancel, this);
                builder.setView(dialogLayout);

                return builder.create();
            }

            private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }


            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by just modifying your filter logic.

While comparing your, instead of using **startWith()**, use **contains()** in your filter logic, in adapter, it will return list whose name contains "ger".

Something like this...

```
String aa= "";
String bb = "";
aa.contains(bb);
```

Create Filter Object with all required implementations, and with your logic.

```
Filter customFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        }
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
      }
}
```

Then override, your adapter's filter method and return **customFilter** object.

```
 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
    return customFilter;
}
```

Refer to this solution to know more...

[Custom getFilter in custom ArrayAdapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android)

Comment: ohh.. sorry my mistake, it would be contains() instead of containsWith().

Comment: How and Where should I use? I'm using ArrayAdapter.

Comment: okay, post your getFilter() method logic. You have to use it inside that method, where you are filtering your result. Post the method.

Comment: It's android's self method

Comment: yeah, you need to override the filter logic in adapter class.

Comment: I'm using ArrayAdapter. Arrayadapter uses self private ArrayFilter class. I can't  override this. Becouse it uses arrayadapter's private variables. And these variables are not protected. So I cannot use. Is there any way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107350/discussion-between-revenge-and-ritesh).