# How can I filter a listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to filter my listview on depending the name but my  `inputSearch.addTextChangedListener` doesn't work
can you help me to correct it

```
private void showProduct(String json){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String ref = jo.getString("Reference");
                String image1 = "http://aaaa.com/Scripts/images/"+jo.getString("image")+".jpg";
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setName(name);
                product.setRef(ref);
                product.setImageUrl(image1);
                productList.add(product);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getContext(), productList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

inputsearch

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                ((CustomArrayAdapter) ProduitsFragment.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
```

CustomArrayAdapter class

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row2, productList);
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row2, parent, false);
        TextView nom = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
        TextView email2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        nom.setText(productList.get(position).getName()); //make sure nom is for name and email2 is for ref. This is just my guesswork.
        email2.setText(productList.get(position).getRef());

        Picasso.with(context).load(productList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: We may need to see the `CustomArrayAdapter` class. Also, that cast shouldn't be necessary if you declared the adapter as that type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom getFilter in custom ArrayAdapter in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android)

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited my post

Comment: is `onTextChanged` being called? add some `Log.d` inside and see the logcat

Comment: @cricket_007 I couldn't use the code of this link in my case. Can you help me please

Comment: @pskink yes it's called I write d and I got D/txt: d with Log.d("txt", cs.toString());

Comment: so override `Product#toString` method returning `name` for example

Comment: You should make a class like `ProductFilter extends Filter`, then you implement the `performFiltering` and `publishResults` methods, then you override `getFilter` to `return new ProductFilter`.... Pretty sure anything I answer with is already discussed in that post.

Comment: @pskink I couldn't understand your remark very well.  What should I do exactly ?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks I will check this

Comment: override the method `String toString()` in `Product` class

Comment: or just use [that](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> implements  Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    ArrayList<Product> mFilterList;
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row2, productList);
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
        this.mFilterList = productList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row2, parent, false);
        TextView nom = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
        TextView email2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        nom.setText(productList.get(position).getName()); //make sure nom is for name and email2 is for ref. This is just my guesswork.
        email2.setText(productList.get(position).getRef());

        Picasso.with(context).load(productList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        return rowView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }
    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.e("Here the value",constraint.toString());
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Product> firstFilterList = new ArrayList<Product>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < mFilterList.size(); i++) {
                            if ( (mFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())||
                                    mFilterList.get(i).getRef().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())
                            )) {

                                Product _product = new Product(
                                        mFilterList.get(i).getRef() ,
                                        mFilterList.get(i).getName()
                                );

                                firstFilterList.add(_product);
                            }
                        }
                        results.count = firstFilterList.size();
                        results.values = firstFilterList;

            } else {

                        results.count = mFilterList.size();
                        results.values = mFilterList;

            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                      final FilterResults results) {

            productList = (ArrayList<Product>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

*inputsearch*
Implement this in your Activity class

```
 implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
```

and override the following two methods

```
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            newText = WordUtils.capitalize(newText);
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

and in your on create add this

```
        inputSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(Search_Books.this);
```

Comment: no, dont do that, it will not only not work (getCount() will always return original `productList` size) but also it is pointless to create the new adapter from the scratch if you want to change `Product` to `Product2` / `ImportedProduct` / whatever, write a generic adapter instead based on `ArrayAdapter`