# ArrayAdapter Reverse getFilter(),filter

Tags: java, filter, android-arrayadapter

I am developing an app with an `ArrayAdapter<String> abc;`

For this adapter need to use a filter:

```
abc.getFilter().filter("*#*");
```

This is working fine, but now I need to reverse this filter (so that I only see the items which do NOT start with `#`, how can I do this?

Comment: You have to write your own filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android

Comment: thank you, I think this will work!