# Adapter Search In Android ListView Not Getting Updated

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListView` that contains a `TextView` and `CheckBox`. I am trying to filter my adapter. But can't get the updated result in the `ListView`. The `ListView` just clears on search text entry. I am providing my code below. Thanks for taking time to look at this issue.

**Adapter code**

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup 
 parent) {
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 final View rowView = 
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_doctor_specialties_row, parent, false);
 TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblSpeciality);
    final CheckBox mcheckbox = (CheckBox) 
 rowView.findViewById(R.id.cbSpeciality);
 textView.setText(values[position].getName());
 // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
 String s = values[position].getName();
 if(dh.getSpltiesNameSelected()==null){
   String chkditems = dh.getSpltiesNameSelected().toString();
   if (chkditems.contains(s)) {
       mcheckbox.setChecked(true);
   }
  }

String selectedspecialty=dh.getSpltiesNameSelected().toString();
 if(selectedspecialty.contains(s)){ //for checking the returned data for 
    checked status
    mcheckbox.setChecked(true);
  }
  return rowView;
  }
```

**Activity Code**

```
 final EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US));

 }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                             int arg3) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

   adapter1.getFilter().filter(arg0);

  }

 });
```

Comment: FIrst of all you need to modify `getView()` . Use `ViewHolder` pattern. And to perform filter you need to provide `Filterable` implementation Follow [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android).

Comment: where is `getFilter()` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Complete Demo for this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

Check the link above for more information

**1) Follow holder pattern**

**a) For example, you have 4 views, then define it in holder class**

```
public class ViewHolder {
        TextView rank;
        TextView country;
        TextView population;
        ImageView flag;
    }
```

**b) in a getView method you will set and get this holder class.**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
            holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
            holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            view.setTag(holder);
//set for future use
        } else {
//get from previous object
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
```

It will help to utilize memory effectively

**2) Let's Come to your main issue,**

**a) Understand the use of two lists**

- to filter you need one list as a copy and another list to copy a filtered value
- you can check  the link above, It has two list

//based on text entered in edit text it will change and the list will display based on this.
private List worldpopulationlist = null;

//this copy will not change
private ArrayList arraylist;

**b) understand the logic of filter**

```
// Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**in above logic, It compares and adds into list "worldpopulationlist",
you need to change logic accordingly**

```
if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
```