# Display only subset of list in arrayadapter by values greater than and less than in android

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a list in arrayadapter as shown below,

[image]

I want to only filter only those list with values less than, greater and between values.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter) / [Filterable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Filterable). Here You can see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android) how to to implement and create custom filter.