# How to make a custom Filter for search feature

Tags: android

In my app, I have a list of the user's installed applications and want to create a search function for that list. Right now, here is my coding:

```
       // create new adapter
AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this),   getPackageManager());
// load list application
mListAppInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
// set adapter to list view
mListAppInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
// search bar
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        // When user changed the Text
        // Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
        Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
    });
```

The issue occurs when I get an error on this line:

```
Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

It says that "getFilter()" is not defined in my Base Adapter, which is this:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List mListAppInfo;
private PackageManager mPackManager;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List list, PackageManager pm) {
mContext = c;
mListAppInfo = list;
mPackManager = pm;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// get the selected entry
ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

// reference to convertView
View v = convertView;

// inflate new layout if null
if(v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
}

// load controls from layout resources
ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

// set data to display
ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

// return view
return v;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return filter;
}
}
```

I added the last part "public Filter..." from looking around on stackoverflow. But now, I need a custom filter for the search. What can I use? (I have already tried one thing but it doesn't work)

Comment: If you're displaying a list of items, it would probably make sense to extend `ArrayAdapter` in stead of `BaseAdapter`. `ArrayAdapter` already implements the `Filterable` interface, so by migrating you get a basic filter for free. Alternatively, and especially if you need more control over the actual filtering logic, you can implement your own `Filter`. There are quite a few examples on SO on how to do that - [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14369336/1029225).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getFilter()` is not defined because your adapter has to implements the Filterable interface, so just add  "implements Filterable" on your adapter:

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    // your stuff
}
```

and in your getFilter

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null) {
        filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<ApplicationInfo> myFilteredAppList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : originalListAppInfo) {
                    String somefield = appInfo.getSomeField();
                    if (somefield.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        myFilteredAppList.add(appInfo);
                    }
                }
                results.count = myFilteredAppList.size();
                results.values = myFilteredAppList;
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mListAppInfo = (List<ApplicationInfo>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    return filter;
}
```

notice that I've iterated throuh a copy of the original list (originalListAppInfo), created during the creation of the adapter.

```
private List<ApplicationInfo> originalListAppInfo;
private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;

private Filter filter;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> listApp) {
    this.context = context;
    this.originalListAppInfo = this.mListAppInfo = listApp;
}
```

Hope this help. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm except for two errors on this line:
String somefield = appInfo.getSomeField();
and this line:
myFilteredAppList.add(site);
saying that "getSomeField();" is undefined and that "site" cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: The only quick fix for "getSomeField" is to add a cast type to AppInfo

Comment: and then for "site" it of course says to create things but it also says that I can change it to appInfo. Should I do that?

Comment: I put "someField" because of course I don't know from which field you want to filter and I don't know how the ApplicationInfo is made! Btw yes, you should change the "site" to "appInfo", my bad. Remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted if it worked! :)