# Android: filter ListView without the adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, adapter

I have a ListView that gets filled by SimpleAdapter, this adapter is local variable inside the procedure that fills the ListView.

Now, I want to filter the ListView, but I have no access to the adapter in the EditText events

is there a way to do that?

```
I tried MyListView.getAdapter().getFilter().Filter("some text");
```

but that gives error as getFilter does not exist for MyListView.getAdapter()

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `listView.setFilterText` (you need to `setFilterTextEnabled` too)

Comment: setFilterText does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare adapter as global, setting adapter as global will let you filter it:

```
 YourActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter("some text");
```

Did you try this?, it should works:

```
 Adapter adapter= MyListView.getAdapter();
 adapter.getFilter().filter("some text");
```

Too you can post your code to check what are you doing wrong, if you're using a custom adapter you have to implement the getFilter method

Comment: this does not work Adapter adapter= MyListView.getAdapter();
 adapter.getFilter().filter("some text");

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter) post might answer your question. You have to create `getFilter()` in your adapter.