# Filter Dynamic listview android

Tags: android, listview, filter

Hello i have made a dynamic listview..Now i want to add filter in listview.if i enter text in edittext then item which mathces the search should display..have called addTextChangedListener to my edittext..and called a method filter in my adapter..but m not getting any idea what should i write in my filter method as it is a dynamic listview...

Here is my code:

```
    package com.XXXXX.XXXXX;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.XXXXX.adapter.UpdateSingleItemViewActivity;
import com.XXXXX.adapter.UpdatesAdapterList;
import com.XXXXX.local.database.DBController;
import com.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.constant.Constant;
import com.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.utils.Utility;

public class Cardiology_updates extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnRefreshListener {
    EditText et ;
    private Context appContext;
    // ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private boolean isFinish = false;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UpdatesHmList;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FinalLocalDataList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> LocalDataList;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues;
    ListView list;
    UpdatesAdapterList adapter;
    public static String UpdateID = "UpdateID";
    public static String UpdateTitle = "Title";
    /*
     * public static String UpdateDescription = "Description"; public static
     * String POPULATION = "UpdateDate"; public static String UpdateImage =
     * "Photo";
     */

    public static String UpdateDescription = "Description";
    public static String POPULATION = "Title";
    public static String UpdateImage = "Complete_imagePath";

    public static String Complete_imagePath;
    public static String Title;
    public static String Description;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardiology_updates);
//      controller.deleteAllJsonData();
        appContext = this;
        animationView();
        initComponent();

    }

    private void animationView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);


        dialog = new Dialog(appContext);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk)).setOnClickListener(this);

        new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.Button01) {

            finish();
            // finishActivity() ;
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnOk) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (isFinish) {
                this.finish();
            }

        }
    }

    public class GetUpdatesInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (progressbar.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Create an array
            UpdatesHmList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            String url = null;

            url = Constant.serverUrl + "/GetUpdateList";
            result = Utility.postParamsAndfindJSON(url);
            Log.e("result doInBackground", "" + result);
            if (!(result == null)) {
                try {
                    controller.deleteAllJsonData();
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("UpdateID", jsonobject.getString("UpdateID"));
                        map.put("Title", jsonobject.getString("Title"));

                        String Upadates_Photo = jsonobject.optString("Photo")
                                .toString();

                        String Complete_imagePath = Constant.prifixserverUrl
                                + Upadates_Photo;
                        String Title = jsonobject.getString("Title").toString();
                        String Description = jsonobject
                                .getString("Description").toString();

                        String noHtml = Description.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

                        String parseResponse = noHtml.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");

                        map.put("Photo", Complete_imagePath);
                        map.put("Description", Description);
                        map.put("UpdateDate",
                                jsonobject.getString("UpdateDate"));

                        Log.e("UpdateID ",
                                " "
                                        + jsonobject.getString("UpdateID")
                                                .toString());
                        Log.e("Title ", " "
                                + jsonobject.getString("Title").toString());
                        Log.e("Complete_imagePath ",
                                " " + Complete_imagePath.toString());

                        Log.e("Description ", " " + parseResponse);

                        Log.e("UpdateDate ",
                                " "
                                        + jsonobject.getString("UpdateDate")
                                                .toString());

                        queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        queryValues.put("Complete_imagePath",
                                Complete_imagePath);
                        queryValues.put("Title", Title);
                        queryValues.put("Description", Description);
                        controller.insertAllJsonData(queryValues);
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        UpdatesHmList.add(map);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            if (progressbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            /*
             * if (result == null) { //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
             * localalldata();
             * 
             * }
             */
            localalldata();

            /*
             * list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Upadates); // Pass the
             * results into ListViewAdapter.java adapter = new
             * UpdatesAdapterList(Cardiology_updates.this, FinalLocalDataList);
             * // Set the adapter to the ListView list.setAdapter(adapter);
             */

            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             getSomeData();
//              localalldata();
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);

    }

    protected void getSomeData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // localalldata();
        new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        /*
         * if (LocalDataList == null) { Log.e("LocalDataList inside if ",
         * "LocalDataList inside if "); new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();
         * 
         * } else { // adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
         * Log.e("LocalDataList else ", "LocalDataList else  ");
         * 
         * adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
         */

    }

    private void localalldata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LocalDataList = controller.getAllJsonData();
        FinalLocalDataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : LocalDataList) {
            System.out.println(hashMap.keySet());
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(hashMap.get(key));

                Complete_imagePath = hashMap.get("Complete_imagePath");
                Title = hashMap.get("Title");
                Description = hashMap.get("Description");

                map.put("Complete_imagePath", Complete_imagePath);
                map.put("Title", Title);
                map.put("Description", Description);
                Log.v("All Json CodiateUpdate Title", "" + Complete_imagePath);
                Log.v("All Json CodiateUpdate Title", "" + Title);
            }
            FinalLocalDataList.add(map);
        }
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Upadates);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new UpdatesAdapterList(Cardiology_updates.this,
                FinalLocalDataList);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        // Capture Text in EditText
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                //String text = et.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            }
        });

         }



         }
```

Here is my adapter class includes filter:

```
    package com.XXXXX.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.XXXXX.XXXXX.Cardiology_updates;
import com.XXXXX.XXXXX.R;
import com.XXXXX.imageloader.ImageLoader;

public class UpdatesAdapterList extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
      private Activity activity;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public UpdatesAdapterList(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView UpdateTitle;
        TextView country;
        TextView population;
        ImageView UpdateImage;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_updateitem, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        UpdateTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUpdatetitle);
        //country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    //  population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        UpdateImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_UpdateImage);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        UpdateTitle.setText(resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));
    //  country.setText(resultp.get(UpdatesActivity.COUNTRY));
    //  population.setText());
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage), UpdateImage);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateSingleItemViewActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("UpdateTile", resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("UpdateDescription", resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateDescription));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.POPULATION));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("UpdateImage", resultp.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

               FilterResults results;
               ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredList;

               @Override
               protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                   // Has the filtered values
                   data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;  
                   notifyDataSetChanged();          
               }

               @Override
               protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                   // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                   results = new FilterResults();
                   filteredList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                   //This is the search string user typed in EditText. 
                   String searchString = constraint.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());

                   /*
                    * Code to update the filteredList based on Search String.
                    * 
                    * I'm just writing pseudo code for search, based on
                    * Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle
                    */ 
                    int mCount=data.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> obj= data.get(i);
                        String updateTitle=obj.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle);
                        if(updateTitle.contains(searchString)){
                             filteredList.add(obj);
                        }
                    } 

                   synchronized (this) {
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = filteredList.size();
                        results.values = filteredList;
                    }

                return results;
            }

         };
       return filter;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface in your UpdatesAdapterList class.

For detailed explanation visit [How to implement getfilter() with custom adapter that extends baseadapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter#14369336).

```
public class UpdatesAdapterList extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
 ...

 @Override
 public Filter getFilter(){
      // Your Search logic goes here..
     Filter filter = new Filter() {
           FilterResults results;
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredList;

           @Override
           protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
               // Has the filtered values
               data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;  
               notifyDataSetChanged();          
           }

           @Override
           protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
               // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
               results = new FilterResults();
               filteredList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

               //This is the search string user typed in EditText. 
               String searchString = constraint.toString();

               /*
                * Code to update the filteredList based on Search String.
                * 
                * I'm just writing pseudo code for search, based on
                * Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle
                */ 
                int mCount=data.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> obj= data.get(i);
                    String updateTitle=obj.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle);
                    if(updateTitle.contains(searchString)){
                         filteredList.add(obj);
                    }
                } 

               synchronized (this) {
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = filteredList.size();
                    results.values = filteredList;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

     };
   return filter;
 }

}
```

Comment: M not getting any idea what to writte in the logic section..:(

Comment: My listview is getting filtered perfectly but while backpressing button to clear edittext listview is not getting updated.

Comment: any solution for my query??

Comment: can anybody help me to solve my problem mention above:(