# How to dismiss a "bubble text" always displaying when typing text in android.widget.SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

I have a listview of apps and a SearchView on ActionBar. When typing text to filter apps by their name. It works but there is always a pop-up with a searching text overlapping the listview.

It can be seen in the picture below marked by a red rectangle.
I don't know how to make it disappear. Please give me an idea :)

[image]

Comment: see setTextFilterEnabled()

Comment: Thanks pskink for answering but my list view cannot be searched without this function. Do you have any way?

Comment: how do you perform list filtering?

Comment: I cannot tell you in detail about my app but what I've done is based on a tutorial at:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter/14369336#14369336

Comment: so i cannot help you them...