# Android: Searchview not working

Tags: android, searchview

I am using this code to search words in my dictionary:

The Dictionary list:

```
final List<String> letters;

    letters = getAllLetters();
    adapter= new adapterRow(getApplicationContext(), letters);

    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the search method:

```
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dictionary, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Dictionary.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I click the search icon it opens the textbox and I can write my input in it, but it does not filter anything. I cannot find what the problem is.
Thanks in advance

the menu:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search" android:title="Search"
    android:orderInCategory="80" app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:enabled="true"  android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" >

</item>
```

The adapter class:

```
   private Context context;
        private List <String> listSounds;
        public adapterRow(Context context, List<String> friends) {
            super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, friends);
            this.context=context;
            this.listSounds=friends;
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listSounds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView one;
        TextView two;
        int position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View customView=convertView;
        if(customView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

           customView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,null);
        }
        String name = listSounds.get(position);
ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
       holder.one = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.two = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      holder.one.setText(name);
      holder.two.setText("Defintion");
```

Comment: what is adapterRow class (btw don't use lowercase class name)? also what is `getAllLetters()` like?

Comment: adapterRow is the adapter class. And getAllLetters just puts "Mitochnodria", "Stuff" in the List View

Comment: post the sources of that class and method... (i know that `adapterRow` is  the adapter class)

Comment: @pskink ok I posted the adapter class as well. Hope you can help

Comment: and where is source of `getAllLetters()` ?

Comment: @pskink it is just:
list.add("Mitochnodria");
list.add("Stuff");

Comment: @pskink and of course return list;

Comment: your adapter doesn't implement `android.widget.Filterable` interface, use the adapter which does, like `android.widget.ArrayAdapter`

Comment: No sir I am using the widget array adapter

Comment: *The widget adapter and the widget.Filterable

Comment: so why are you overriding `getCount`, `getItem` and `getItemId` ? do you understand what are they for?

Comment: Oh! It was a fix suggestion a while ago. I removed them. Now when I search for something it just shows me the first result

Comment: When I search St, instead of showing Stuff, it shows just Mitochondria

Comment: post the adapter code again, *ALL* the  code

Comment: That is the whole new code, without getCOunt, getItemId and getIten

Comment: no, it is NOT, post the WHOLE adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code inside `onQueryTextChange()`

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
    myList.clearTextFilter();
} else {
    myList.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);
}
```

Comment: myList is the List<String> letters right? Because if so there is no such method.

Comment: No. myList is your ListView object.

Comment: sorry my bad. Still there is no such method .getAdapter.getFilter. Instead I used .setFilter. Yet no change

Comment: I thought you already have get filter function. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter

Comment: ok I read through them and I do not know what all this original data, etc. is, but they appear to be using BaseAdapter while I am using ArrayAdapter. Probably does not matter. Still the code does not work.