# Unable to add image in a istview from the database

Tags: android, listview

to display images in a listview I used picasso but I got this error

```
06-14 11:07:10.780 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/value:: [{"Reference":"QNPD2016","Nom":"ERK","Description":"done","image":"image1"},{"Reference":"TTGH25361","Nom":"PSD","Description":"usage","image":"image2"}]
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
    06-14 11:07:10.800 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
    06-14 11:07:10.824 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.824 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image1
    06-14 11:07:10.828 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image2: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.832 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image2
    06-14 11:07:10.840 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.844 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image1
    06-14 11:07:10.844 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image2: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.848 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image2
    06-14 11:07:10.848 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.852 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image1
    06-14 11:07:10.884 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image2: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    06-14 11:07:10.884 1197-1197/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image2
```

How can I correct this error 
This is my code

I used json and picasso.
I already dislayed an image using this code but when I tried to use it with a listview it doesn't work

```
public class ResultFragment extends Fragment implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    private String JSON_STRING;
    private ImageButton btn1;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    public static final String URL = "http://aaaaa.com/PHP/getAllRes.php";
    //public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    // List view
    private ListView listView;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    private ImageView imageView1;
    LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_produits, container, false);
        listView  = (ListView)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        inputSearch  = (EditText)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        imageView1= (ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        layout=(LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                ((SimpleAdapter) ProduitsFragment.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
        getJSON();
        return rootview;
    }

    private void showProduct(String json){
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            try {
                JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
                for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                    String ref = jo.getString("Reference");
                    String image1 = jo.getString("image");
                    final ImageView im =new ImageView (getActivity());
                    Picasso.with(getActivity())
                            .load("http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+image1+".jpg")
                            .resize(50, 50)
                            .into(im);
                    //layout.addView(im);
                    HashMap<String,String> product= new HashMap<>();
                    product.put("name",name);
                    product.put("ref",ref);
                    product.put("image1",image1);
                    list.add(product);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row,
                    new String[]{"image1","ref","name"},
                    new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.nom, R.id.email2});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Téléchargement", "Veuillez patientez...", false, false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                Log.e("value: ", JSON_STRING);
                showProduct(s);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduit.class);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String tid = map.get("ref").toString();
        intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Edit
CustomArrayAdapter .java

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredData;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
        super(context, R.layout.listrow2, productList);
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow2, parent, false);
        TextView nom = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
        TextView email2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        nom.setText(productList.get(position).getName()); //make sure nom is for name and email2 is for ref. This is just my guesswork.
        email2.setText(productList.get(position).getRef());

        Picasso.with(context).load(productList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        return rowView;
    }
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
                if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
                {
                    results.values = productList;
                    results.count = productList.size();
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                    for(HashMap<String,String> data : productList)
                    {
                        //In this loop, you'll filter through originalData and compare each item to charSequence.
                        //If you find a match, add it to your new ArrayList
                        //I'm not sure how you're going to do comparison, so you'll need to fill out this conditional
                        if(data matches your filter criteria)
                        {
                            filterResultsData.add(data);
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = filterResultsData;
                    results.count = filterResultsData.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
            {
                filteredData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I want to get a listview like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OprvV.png)

This is my filezilla screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqNhb.png)

Comment: It's a `FileNotFoundException`. This means that there is nothing at `http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/image1.jpg`. There is no `image1.jpg` inside the "`http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/`" url.

Comment: There 2 images in this url. I already displayed them in an other activity

Comment: Maybe, but the names of these two images are not "image1.jpg" as you have specified in this line: `Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load("http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+image1+".jpg")
                        .resize(50, 50)
                        .into(im);`  Find out the exact filenames of those images.

Comment: The names are correct. I updated my post with the FileZilla screenshot

Comment: Yes, dear. I'm really sorry for the superficial glance earlier. Now that I looked at your code more closely, I have a few questions. Why are you doing this: `final ImageView im =new ImageView (getActivity());
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load("http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+image1+".jpg")
                        .resize(50, 50)
                        .into(im);`, Why are you passing an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s into your adapter, and Can you show me the code for your `SimpleAdapter`?

Comment: `resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri` usually appears if the system is trying to pull a drawable bitmap from your app's resource directories and there is no image there. This is why I asked for your adapter's code because ideally that's where you bind the `itemViews` to the `ListView`.

Comment: I used picasso to load the images from the url The SimpleAdapter is already shown in my first post  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row,
                new String[]{"image1","ref","name"},
                new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.nom, R.id.email2});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: So you are using the default implementation of `SimpleAdapter`. In that case, you cannot use images. `SimpleAdapter` only supports `TextView`s. You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html). Let me know if you need help writing a custom adapter.

Comment: thanks so how can I use a custom adapter in my case?

Comment: Edit your question to give me an idea of what you're trying to achieve. I'll try to give you a working solution. :)

Comment: Thanks! Post a sample of your JSON as well. I'll be using a custom `ArrayAdapter` instead of a `SimpleAdapter`. Would that be okay?

Comment: My JSON is already show in my first post GetJSON(). The most important is to have a listview with an image

Comment: I posted my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really sorry for the late reply. `resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri` usually appears if the system is trying to pull a drawable bitmap from your app's resource directories and there is no image there. Since you are using the default implementation of `SimpleAdapter`, you cannot use images. SimpleAdapter only supports TextViews. So, you need to do the following:

Create a plain old Java class called `Product` like so:

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    String ref;
    String imageUrl;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getRef() {
    return ref;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setRef(String ref) {
    this.ref = ref;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
}
```

Create your custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Product> productList;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
    super(context, R.layout.listrow, productList);
    this.context = context;
    this.productList = productList;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent, false);
    TextView nom = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    TextView email2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    nom.setText(productList.get(position).getName()); //make sure nom is for name and email2 is for ref. This is just my guesswork.
    email2.setText(productList.get(position).getRef());

    Picasso.with(context).load(productList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Now, modify your `showProduct` thus:

```
private void showProduct(String json){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String ref = jo.getString("Reference");
                String image1 = "http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+jo.getString("image")+".jpg";
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setName(name);
                product.setRef(ref);
                product.setImageUrl(image1);
                productList.add(product);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getContext(), productList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

**EDIT**

Make these changes to `onItemClick`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduit.class);
    Product product = (Product) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String tid = product.getRef();
    intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thanks it works very well knowing that I replaced LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); by LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); because I had an error

Comment: How can I change this method because I have an error with adapter public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter) ResultFragment.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it works. Please also mark my answer as "accepted" so that people reading this post know that your issue with Picasso was resolved. If you tell me what you're trying to achieve with `((SimpleAdapter) ResultFragment.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs); `, I may be able to help you with that as well. :)

Comment: As for your filtering, you can also go through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter) and implement a custom filter in your adapter class. Let me know if you need any further help with that as well. :)

Comment: thanks How can I add a custom filter? I edited my post. I added the getFilter) method in the CustomArrayAdapter but what can I add in the if()  if(data matches your filter criteria)
                        {
                            filterResultsData.add(data);
                        } How can I use it in my inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() method?

Comment: That depends upon what you want from your filter, Lara. Do you want to filter the `ListView` depending on the name, ref, or imageUrl? Usually, the `CharSequence` is matched against a `String` in the objects in the dataset.

Comment: I want to filter the listView depending on the name

Comment: The onItemClick stops workig also. I have an error FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dell.app3.Product cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap CODE public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduct.class); HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); String tid = map.get("ref").toString(); intent.putExtra("ref", tid); startActivity(intent); }

Answer (score 0):

> /BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:

This means the url for image you have provided doesn't contain any image. Please check: `http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+image1+".jpg` 
for `image1.jpg` in specific folder.

**Edit**
If you have image under same url then try changing url as:

`"http://aaaaa.com/PHP/images/"+"image1.jpg"`

Comment: There 2 images in this url (image1.jpg and image2.jpg). I already displayed them in an other activity

Comment: @LaraFab with same url?

Comment: I got the same error why I got image2 in the error with a static url?E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-14 12:57:47.596 2545-2545/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image1
06-14 12:57:47.600 2545-2545/com.example.dell.app2 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image2: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-14 12:57:47.600 2545-2545/com.example.dell.app2 I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: image2

Comment: There is a repetion 3 times image1 image2 image1 image2 image1 image2 as shown in my first post