# Updating dataset of ArrayAdapter for List with SearchView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, searchview

I've got an array adapter to feed to my listview which also contains a searchview. The adapter contains 2 array lists, say A & B. A & B both initially hold all the items to display & subsequently B contains the filtered results of the search (done by implementing the setOnQueryTextListener, onQueryTextChange and filtering the adapter here). On search closure, all items of B are replenished from A. All items can be deleted by tapping them. The issue's I'm having are as follows:

1. say A has 10 items & B has 3 items (with search in progress). If
   I delete an item from B, the same is not removed from A (due to A
   populating B when closing search)
2. the same happens when adding an item (via a floating action button) when search is in progress, since B is the active list that populates the list view. A is not updated in this case.

Calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't seem to work. What I'm looking for is for arrays A & B to always be consistent i.e. adding/removing an item removes it from both when search is in progress. Am I required to add methods to my adapter that need to be called each time an item is added/removed wherein I need to check if a search is in progress & appropriately handle the case? It doesn't seem like an optimal solution. I'm relatively new to Android development so I hope someone can point me in the right direction as I couldn't find solutions to a question similar to mine. Thanks!

Comment: you need to read about `Filterable` interface and `Filter` class, `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` is a normal way of filtering out the items

Comment: the problem is not so much filtering as it is the updates done during the filtering/search. A quick search about it doesn't really seem to point to a solution to my issue :( e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14369336/1113598 and such

Comment: study that generic [adapter](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0/raw/10aa5bc585d97596485bdc714fb8e13b199fff3a/MatchableArrayAdapter.java), note private `ArrayFilter` class, the adapter is based on std `ArrayAdapter` class with 2 small but very useful changes described in the comment

Comment: ok i checked the adapter, other than the filtering, i see add/remove/clear etc. methods on the adapter which map the changes on both the data sets i.e. actual list & filtered list so is there any particular advantage to this method of filtering compared to what I was doing? maybe I'm missing something obvious here..

Comment: `add/remove/clear` are used to modify the adapter content, they are not intended to be used when filtering, when filtering only `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` should be used

Comment: so its only the 'preferred' way of filtering, thats it ? i sense miscommunication here as suggested in my question, i was asking if i need to write additional add/remove methods on my adapter to handle the addition & removal of data from my arrays if there was no other way; which seems in line with their implementation in the adapter that you shared

Comment: yes it is, you can also use `ListView#setFilterText` but under the hood it also calls `getFilter().filter(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115082/discussion-between-akdsouza-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution turned out to be far simpler as I was on the right track. All I had to do was to add a public method to the adapter which I called for all such add/remove operations regardless of whether the operation was done when filtering or not. In case of removal, inside this public method I just removed the object from the original & filtered data source. Removing from the original, also removed it from the main array list (in the fragment in which the listing was displayed) by reference. Only important thing to note is that to get the correct object to be removed, I added another method that returned the object from the filtered list (which is always the active datasource) based on the position at which the removal was issued. This was important since if the main list had say 4 items, but the removal was done for the 1st item when filtering (which occupies say the 3rd position in the main list), the incorrect object would be removed i.e. the 1st item in the main list. Hope this helps anyone who comes across such a scenario.