# getFilter() on a custom ArrayAdapter not working

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter, android-filterable, android-filter

I am using a **Custom ArrayAdapter** to store User information for example sammy, robert, lizie are each one User objects and i am using a User type **ArrayList** to store all the User objects to **ArrayList**.

And because it is not a string or int (The ArrayList) the default **getFilter** does not work, and i have done my research but it is really confusing how the **getFilter** method works so i can modify myself.

**I want to implement the searching based on the** `name` property form the `User class`

I know i have to implement the **Filterable** interface in my **CustomAdapter** class, but the **getFilter** is really unintuitive.

**Here is my CustomAdapter**

```
class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>  implements Filterable {


    CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        User innserUser = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        }

        TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userNameContact);
        TextView userNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userNumberContact);
        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImageContact);

        try {
            if(innserUser != null) {
                username.setText(innserUser.name);
                userNumber.setText(innserUser.number);
                userImage.setImageBitmap(innserUser.imageBitmap);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }


}
```

**and here is the user class nothing special here**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class User {

    String id, name, number;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;

    User(String id, String name, String number, Bitmap imageBitmap){

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.imageBitmap = imageBitmap;

    }
}
```

I tied alot of variations of the **getFilter** from many threads but none of them work for me ,and the one's with good explanations are for BaseAdapter not for ArrayAdapter

I have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter) and i have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android/14663821#14663821) but does not work for me.

I am new to android development field, and this seems particularly unintuitive.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated, thank you.

***EDIT 1***: After the answer of **jitesh mohite**, Thanks for the replay **jitesh mohite**

```
class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>  implements Filterable {


    ArrayList<User> users;

    CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
        this.users = users;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        User innserUser = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        }

        TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userNameContact);
        TextView userNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userNumberContact);
        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImageContact);

        try {
            if(innserUser != null) {
                username.setText(innserUser.name);
                userNumber.setText(innserUser.number);
                userImage.setImageBitmap(innserUser.imageBitmap);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }


    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<User> tempList=new ArrayList<User>();
            // Add the filter code here
            if(constraint != null && users != null) {
                int length= users.size();
                int i=0;
                while(i<length){
                    User item= users.get(i);
                    //do whatever you wanna do here
                    //adding result set output array

                    //item.name is user.name cause i want to search on name
                    if(item.name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) ) { // Add check here, and fill the tempList which shows as a result

                        tempList.add(item);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
                //following two lines is very important
                //as publish result can only take FilterResults users
                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
            users = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return myFilter;
    }


}
```

***the search is not working on the customadapter still i think i am doing something wrong.***

here i am typing something in the search bar but no filtering happens

[image]

**and if you want to see the searchbar code its nothing special just the usual**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_box, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            customArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });


    return true;



}
```

Comment: You can use `ArrayAdapter`'s built-in `Filter` as long as your model class returns the `String` you want to use for comparisons from its `toString()` method. That is, simply `@Override public String toString() { return name; }` in your `User` class. You won't need a specialized `Filter` class or `getFilter()` method at all.

Comment: Mike M. it worked flawlessly with the easy straightforward approach

Comment: please make this an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter`'s built-in `Filter` uses the `toString()` return from the model class (i.e., its type parameter) to perform its filtering comparisons. You don't necessarily need a custom `Filter` implementation if you're able to override `User`'s `toString()` method to return what you want to compare (provided its filtering algorithm is suitable to your situation). In this case:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

To be clear on exactly what that algorithm is, `ArrayAdapter`'s default filtering goes as follows:

The filter `String` is first converted to lowercase. Then, looping over the dataset, each value's `toString()` return is converted to lowercase, and checked to see if it `startsWith()` the filter `String`. If so, it's added to the result set. If not, a second check is performed, whereby the value's lowercase `String` is split on a space (`" "`), and each value from that is compared to the filter, again using `startsWith()`. Basically, it first checks if the whole thing starts with the filter text, and then checks each word, if necessary.

If that's a suitable filter, then this solution is by far the simplest.

---

If that does not meet your needs, and you do actually need a custom `Filter` implementation, then you should just not use `ArrayAdapter` to begin with. `ArrayAdapter` maintains internal, `private List`s for the original and filtered collections – initially populated from the collection passed in the constructor call – and you do not have access to those. This is why the custom `Filter` attempt shown does not work, as the displayed item count and the item returned from `getItem(position)` are coming from that internal filter `List`, not the one built in the custom `Filter`.

In that case, you should directly subclass `BaseAdapter` instead, maintaining your own `List`s for the original and filtered collections. You can use [`ArrayAdapter`'s source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) as a guide.

Indeed, `ArrayAdapter` is often the wrong choice when choosing an `Adapter` to extend. `ArrayAdapter` is designed for a singular, somewhat simplistic goal: setting a flat `String` on a single `TextView` in each list item. There are several cases in which subclassing `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter` is rather pointless and/or redundant. For example:

- Overriding `getView()` and not using the `View` returned from a call to `super.getView()`.
- Manually setting the text on the `TextView` yourself, for whatever reason.
- Maintaining and using your own collections; i.e., the arrays, or `List`s, or what have you.

In these and certain other cases, it's arguably better to use `BaseAdapter` from the start. Using `ArrayAdapter` for anything much more complex than single text items with basic functionality can quickly become cumbersome and error-prone, and is often more trouble than it's worth.

---

Lastly, I would mention that `ListView` is basically deprecated, at this point, though not yet officially, at the time of this writing. Current recommendations are to use `RecyclerView` instead. However, for those brand new to Android programming, `ListView` can still be useful as a beginning step in understanding the overall design of this type of recycling adapter `View`. `RecyclerView` can be a little overwhelming to start with.

Comment: Straightforward and easy solution,

Answer (score 1):

```
Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
         ArrayList<User> tempList=new ArrayList<User>();
         // Add the filter code here
         if(constraint != null && users!=null) {
             int length= users.size();
             int i=0;
                while(i<length){
                    User item= users.get(i);
                    //do whatever you wanna do here
                    //adding result set output array    
                    if()  {  // Add check here, and fill the tempList which shows as a result

                    tempList.add(item);
                  }

                    i++;
                }
                //following two lines is very important
                //as publish result can only take FilterResults users
                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
          }
          return filterResults;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
          users = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
          if (results.count > 0) {
           notifyDataSetChanged();
          } else {
              notifyDataSetInvalidated();
          }  
      }
     };
```

**Lastly, Override this method and return filter instance.**

```
@Override
     public Filter getFilter() {
        return myFilter;
    }
```

For more reference see https://gist.github.com/tobiasschuerg/3554252

Comment: what does the users stand for here ? the main user ArrayList that the adapter takes ? in the constructor ?

Comment: i have edited based on your answer but i think i am doing something wrong, i am pasting the new edited class in a new edit

Comment: Can you explain in brief whats the problem?

Comment: i have added the modified customadapter in the edit after your answer, and searching still not work

Comment: Add debug point inside publishResults() and check the value of list ---users = (ArrayList<User>) results.values--- This list should be filtered one. If it is correct then check after notifyDatasetChange how many times getview() gets called

Comment: please check my edited answer, does my edits look ok ? or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183427/discussion-between-jitesh-mohite-and-shantanu-shady).