# Implementing search functionality on ListView

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am using parse server for my database. I wanted to get the item while user search on the search function. I search on the google for this but did not found anything suitable.

#MainActivity

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    
    //get the search view and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    //searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    //assumes the current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
     searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
   // searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) this);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
         
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return true;
        }
    });



    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

    //pauseSomeStuff();
    return super.onSearchRequested();
}
```

### RoomCardRecyclerViewAdapter

I wanted to get item from this adapter by using search functionality and filter it for the user

```
private List<ParseObject> mRooms = new ArrayList<>();
private ParseObject room;
private String mSection;

public RoomCardRecyclerViewAdapter(){
    super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
}
public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ParseObject>  DIFF_CALLBACK = new 
DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull ParseObject oldItem, @NonNull ParseObject newItem) {
        return oldItem.getObjectId() == newItem.getObjectId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull ParseObject oldItem, @NonNull ParseObject newItem) {
        return (oldItem.getUpdatedAt().equals(newItem.getUpdatedAt()) && 
 oldItem.getCreatedAt().equals(newItem.getCreatedAt()));
    }
};


public RoomCardRecyclerViewAdapter(String section) {
  this();
  this.mSection = section;
}
public class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    protected ImageView mRoomImage;
    protected TextView mRoomPrice;
    protected TextView mInclusiveOrNot;
    protected TextView mPropertyType;
    protected TextView mNumOfBeds;
    protected TextView mNumOfBaths;
    protected TextView mRoomLocation;

    private Context context;

    public RoomViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mRoomImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_image);
        mRoomPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_label);
        mInclusiveOrNot = itemView.findViewById(R.id.incl_excl_label);
        mPropertyType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.propertyType_label);
        mNumOfBeds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.num_beds_label);
        mNumOfBaths = itemView.findViewById(R.id.details_num_baths_label);
        mRoomLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_label);
        this.context = context;
        //set onclick listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("Click event: ", "My room has been clicked.");
        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        Intent intent;
        ParseObject room = getCurrentList().get(pos);

        //create the ParseObject proxy
        ParseProxyObject roomProxy = new ParseProxyObject(room);
        Toast.makeText(context, room.getString("roomSuburb"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //fork to corresponding activity
        if(mSection != null) {
            Log.i("mSection text: ", "mSection text is: " + mSection);
            if (mSection.equals("My Rooms")) {
                //start my rooms detail activity
                Log.i("My room: ", "Room selected " + roomProxy.getObjectId());
                intent = new Intent(context, MyRoomDetailActivity.class);
                //add the room to the intent
                intent.putExtra("currentSelectedRoomObject", room);
                Log.i("Selected room", "Put Extra, " + room);
                intent.putExtra("roomObject", roomProxy);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }else {
            Log.i("My room:", "RoomDetailActivity loaded for MyRoomDetail Activity instead");
            intent = new Intent(context, RoomDetailActivity.class);
            //add the proxy to the intent
            intent.putExtra("roomObject", roomProxy);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflating the viewholder with the appropriate views
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.room_cardview, parent, false);

    return new RoomViewHolder(parent.getContext(), view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    room = getItem(position);
    holder.mRoomLocation.setText(room.getString("roomSuburb"));
    holder.mRoomPrice.setText(Integer.toString(room.getInt("roomMonthlyRent")));
    holder.mInclusiveOrNot.setText(room.getString("roomRentInclusiveOfBills"));
    holder.mPropertyType.setText(room.getString("roomPropertyType"));
    holder.mNumOfBeds.setText(Integer.toString(room.getInt("roomBedrooms")));
    holder.mNumOfBaths.setText(Integer.toString(room.getInt("roomBathrooms")));

    //get the image
    //check if its roomImage or image1 set
    ParseFile imageFile;
    if (room.getParseFile("roomImage") != null){
        //
        imageFile = room.getParseFile("roomImage");
    }else {
        imageFile = room.getParseFile("roomImage1");
    }

    //if there is no image saved in Parse
    if(imageFile == null){
        //continue to load predefined default image
        int r = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        Glide.with(holder.mRoomImage.getContext()).load(r)
                .into(holder.mRoomImage);
    }else {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(imageFile.getUrl());

        //image loader recommended by Google
        Glide.with(holder.mRoomImage.getContext()).load(fileUri.toString())
                .thumbnail(0.6f)
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.mRoomImage);
    }
}


public void addMoreRooms(List<ParseObject> newRooms){
    mRooms.addAll(newRooms);
    submitList((PagedList<ParseObject>) mRooms);
}

public void addAll(List<ParseObject> latestRooms) {
    mRooms.addAll(0, latestRooms);
    //mRooms.add(i, latestRooms);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter(){
  return new Filter() {
      @Override
      protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
          FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
          List<ParseObject> filteredList = null;
          if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
              results.count = mRooms.size();
              results.values = mRooms;

              //results = mRooms.size();
          } else {
              filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
              charSequence = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
              for (ParseObject item : mRooms) {
                  String mSection = item.getObjectId().toLowerCase();
                  filteredList.add(item);
              }
          }

          results.count = filteredList.size();
          results.values = filteredList;

          return results;
      }

      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
          room = (ParseObject) results.values;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

make your adapter `implements Filterable` and take a look for [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter) topic on SO, especially very detailed answer. it's about `BaseAdapter`, but part resposible for filtering is common for all adapters. the clue is to have custom overriden `getFilter()` method in your adapter

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        // implementation of your Filter
        ...
```

and pass `query` from `SearchView` to it by

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    String query - searchView.getText().toString();
    adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sir, i updated my code as you said. But its not working. Its not showing me the list while i m searching.

Comment: your `results.values` is always `= filterResults;`. in `publishResults` method you are updating `mSection` and `mRooms` stays untouched, besides that you have there `ClassCastException`, as `results.values` carries array and you are casting to `String`. Also `getFilteredResults` is doing something, but isn't returning any value (should return filtered array imho)

Comment: sir, can you please help me code it. I m getting confused with this program. I need your help.

Comment: edit your question and post most current version of your code (adapter and `onCreate` of `Activity`), and also source of `ParseObject` and I will edit my answer with some solution

Comment: I have posted my current version my code and the source of ParseObject.

Comment: you've posted `ParseProxyObject` and your adapter is working on `ParseObject` `List`, these aren't same classes...

Comment: I have posted my ParseObject class. But this class is empty.

Comment: `ParseObject` isn't empty, it extends `Room` without any purpose, so its unnecessary... just like posted `ParseProxyObject`, which is irrelevant to your problem. Due to your lack of knowledge about programming, extendsing classes, class casting etc. I can't help you, there is so much problems in your code that I would advice you to learn some basics about Java, then start coding

Comment: Thank you sir for your advice. I realized still i have to learn so many things.