# SearchView filter in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley, searchview

I need help to fix the problem about searchview filter...

here is my code :

activity_kehadiran.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".kehadiran">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kehadiran"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/simpleSearchView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text = "LAPORAN ABSENSI"
        />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kehadiran"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow">
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="TANGGAL ABSENSI"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/tanggal"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="LOKASI IN"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/depof1"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="JAM IN"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/f1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="LOKASI OUT"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/depof4"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="JAM OUT"
                android:id="@+id/f4"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="KETERANGAN"
                android:id="@+id/telat"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#2adcff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:id="@+id/tanggal"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Lokasi Berangkat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/depof1"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Berangkat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/f1"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Lokasi Pulang"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/depof4"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Pulang"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/f4"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="telat"
            android:id="@+id/telat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.eis2.Item;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.eis2.detail_absensi;


import com.example.eis2.R;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<keteranganmodel> {

    public static List<keteranganmodel> movieItemList;

    private Context context;

    public ListViewAdapter(List<keteranganmodel> movieItemList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, movieItemList);
        this.movieItemList = movieItemList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView tanggal = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        TextView depof1 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.depof1);
        TextView f1 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.f1);
        TextView depof4 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.depof4);
        TextView f4 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.f4);
        TextView telat = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.telat);

        keteranganmodel movieItem = movieItemList.get(position);

        tanggal.setText(movieItem.getShift_day());
        depof1.setText(movieItem.getDepo_f1());
        f1.setText(movieItem.getF1());
        depof4.setText(movieItem.getDepo_f4());
        f4.setText(movieItem.getF4());
        telat.setText(movieItem.getKet_absensi());

        // status//
        if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(f1.getText().toString())) {
            f1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(depof1.getText().toString())) {
            depof1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(depof4.getText().toString())) {
            depof4.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(f4.getText().toString())) {
            f4.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

keteranganmodel.java

```
package com.example.eis2.Item;

public class keteranganmodel {
    String shift_day, F1, depo_f1, F4, depo_f4, ket_absensi;

    public keteranganmodel(String shift_day, String F1, String depo_f1, String F4, String depo_f4, String ket_absensi) {
        this.shift_day = shift_day;
        this.F1 = F1;
        this.depo_f1 = depo_f1;
        this.F4 = F4;
        this.depo_f4 = depo_f4;
        this.ket_absensi = ket_absensi;
    }

    public String getShift_day() { return shift_day; }

    public String getF1() {
        return F1;
    }

    public String getDepo_f1() { return depo_f1; }

    public String getF4() { return F4; }

    public String getDepo_f4() {
        return depo_f4;
    }

    public String getKet_absensi() {
        return ket_absensi;
    }
    
}
```

kehadiran.java

```
package com.example.eis2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.eis2.Item.ListViewAdapter;
import com.example.eis2.Item.keteranganmodel;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static com.example.eis2.Item.LoginItem.KEY_NIK;

public class kehadiran extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ListView list;
    private List<keteranganmodel> movieItemList;
    TextView f1;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kehadiran);
        list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        movieItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        f1 = findViewById(R.id.f1);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.simpleSearchView);

        absensi();
    }

    private void absensi() {
        String nik_baru = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_NIK);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://hrd.tvip.co.id/rest_server/api/absensi/index?shift_day=2020-08-24&shift_day_2=2020-08-31&badgenumber=0100028400",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            final JSONArray movieArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {

                                final JSONObject movieObject = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                final keteranganmodel movieItem = new keteranganmodel(
                                        movieObject.getString("shift_day"),
                                        movieObject.getString("F1"),
                                        movieObject.getString("depo_f1"),
                                        movieObject.getString("F4"),
                                        movieObject.getString("depo_f4"),
                                        movieObject.getString("ket_absensi"));


                                movieItemList.add(movieItem);

                            }

                            final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(movieItemList, getApplicationContext());

                            list.setAdapter(adapter);

                            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });

                            Collections.reverse(movieItemList);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

In this case :

[image]

I wanna search 2020-09-16 but this is happen when i use searchview

[image]

So, the main problem is :

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
```

can you guys solve this case ? I appreciate that

Comment: I think u need [notifyDatasetChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Comment: what used for ?

Comment: or maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter)

Comment: @KomangPutra where is getfilter in your adapter..post that first

Comment: i don't have it, but can you give me an example ?

Comment: what do you mean you dont have it..then how are you calling this ==>  adapter.getFilter()

Comment: just see kehadiran.java, i already called adapter.getFilter

Comment: i want you to post up all code of your adapter @KomangPutra listviewadapter

Comment: did you mean getting data from listviewadapter ? i already post it, ListViewAdapter.java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement getfilter() with custom adapter that extends baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365847/how-to-implement-getfilter-with-custom-adapter-that-extends-baseadapter) look at the last answer you need to implement `getFilter()` function which you haven't done

Comment: In ListViewAdapter.java, change `public static List<keteranganmodel> movieItemList;` to `List<keteranganmodel> movieItemList;` and `keteranganmodel movieItem = movieItemList.get(position);` to `keteranganmodel movieItem = getItem(position);`. In keteranganmodel.java, add `@Override public String toString() { return shift_day; }`.

Comment: Thanks, but how i search every string ?

Comment: In keteranganmodel.java, in toString(), change `return shift_day;` to `return shift_day + F1 + depo_f1 + F4 + depo_f4 + ket_absensi;`. I've not use the default filter of ArrayAdapter for quite a long time, so it may not work. If it don't work , then you have to implement the filter code yourselves.