# Filterable adapter not updates listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create search view with popup list with custom adapter. I have filterable interface and my adapter filters,but the filtered list shows incorrect items. Is it any thing I am missing in my code?

**TeamsAdapter.java**

```
    public class TeamsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList<Team> teamsArrayList;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Team> filteredData;

    TeamsFilter mFilter = new TeamsFilter();

    public TeamsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Team> teamsArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.teamsArrayList = teamsArrayList;
        this.filteredData = teamsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if(filteredData == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Team getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.team_list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder.teamNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_name_textview);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.teamNameTextView.setText(teamsArrayList.get(position).getTeamName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView teamNameTextView;
    }

    private class TeamsFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String filterString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

            ArrayList<Team> newList = new ArrayList<>();

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();


            if(teamsArrayList == null || teamsArrayList.size() <= 0){
                filterResults.values = teamsArrayList;
                filterResults.count = teamsArrayList.size();
            }

            int originalListCount = teamsArrayList.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < originalListCount; i++) {
                if(teamsArrayList.get(i).getTeamName().contains(filterString)){
                    newList.add(new Team(teamsArrayList.get(i).getId(),teamsArrayList.get(i).getTeamName()));
                }
            }

            filterResults.values = newList;
            filterResults.count = newList.size();

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<Team>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**SpinnerFragment.java**

```
public class SpinnerFragment extends Fragment {
    /*private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;*/

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private View rootView;
    private SearchView teamsSearchView;
    private PopupWindow popupMessage;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public SpinnerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SpinnerFragment.
     */
    public static SpinnerFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SpinnerFragment fragment = new SpinnerFragment();
        /*Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);*/
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinner, container, false);

        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setText("Testing");

        View popup_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,container,false);
        ListView teamsListView = (ListView) popup_layout.findViewById(R.id.teams_list_view);

        ArrayList<Team> teamsArrayList = new ArrayList<Team>();
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(1,"Sharks"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(2,"Android"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(3,"Google"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(4,"Yahoo"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(5,"Facebook"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(6,"Twitter"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(7,"Apple"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(8,"Amazon"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(9,"Udacity"));
        teamsArrayList.add(new Team(10,"Bosch"));

        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,sortList);

        final TeamsAdapter teamsAdapter = new TeamsAdapter(getActivity(), teamsArrayList);

        teamsListView.setAdapter(teamsAdapter);

        popupMessage = new PopupWindow(popup_layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //popupMessage.setContentView(textView);

        teamsSearchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.teams_search_view);
        teamsSearchView.setQueryHint("Select Team/s");

        teamsSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(hasFocus),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        teamsSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), query,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "newText=>"+newText,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                if(newText.isEmpty()){
                    popupMessage.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }

                //popupMessage.dismiss();
                if(!popupMessage.isShowing()){
                    popupMessage.showAsDropDown(teamsSearchView);
                }

                teamsAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                /*teamsAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFilterComplete(int i) {
                        teamsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });*/
                return true;
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the adapter's Filter object and pass an empty string *.getFilter().filter("") to force a filter after every operation

Deeply explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418939/6028746)

Comment: I already have teamsAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); on my onQueryTextChange. Shall I need to add teamsAdapter.getFilter().filter("); before this line?

Comment: I found it! viewHolder.teamNameTextView.setText(getItem(position).getTeamName()); Used getItem instead of my original array list!

Comment: But still some words are not filterring.For example if I type 'a' it should display my list as "Sharks","Android","Yahoo","Apple","Amazon","Facebook","Udacity". But it displays only "Sharks","Yahoo","Facebook","Amazon","Udacity".I think,is the String contains method not takes first letter?

Comment: Fixed this issue! I forgot to convert original list name to lowercase.if(teamsArrayList.get(i).getTeamName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)). Now Search works great!

Answer (score 0):

**To Solve this issue:**

Use following code in Adapter getView(),

```
viewHolder.teamNameTextView.setText(getItem(position).getTeamName());
```

instead of

```
viewHolder.teamNameTextView.setText(teamsArrayList.get(position).getTeamName());
```

Also,

```
if(teamsArrayList.get(i).getTeamName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
```

instead of,

```
if(teamsArrayList.get(i).getTeamName().contains(filterString))
```